# Missing 'invalid' export from '@sveltejs/kit'

Tags: sveltekit

After updating my SvelteKit project, because Netlify has started giving me some grief, my builds are failing with this error:

`"invalid" is not exported by "node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/index.js", imported by "src/routes/+page.server.ts"`

I have this line in my `+page.server.ts` that's causing the error:

`import { redirect, invalid, error } from "@sveltejs/kit";`

I've looked it up and indeed there is no Invalid export in that `index.js` file.

Before the update, everything was working fine.

Cheers.

Before update, everything worked just fine

Comment: Maybe it was an internal method not meant to be used. You can check the official ones in [here](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#sveltejs-kit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace invalid with fail
import { fail } from '@sveltejs/kit';

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/form-actions

Comment: Thank you very much @Kevin for your time and effort, that worked :-)

Comment: You should format the anwser more. You can use the provided code formatting for qouting the code.